# @gpg decryption failed: no secret key

Tags: pgp

I have copied my PGP key pairs on a newly installed ubuntu server. But they are not working: I get the error "operation cancelled" when trying to decrypt a file:

```
$ echo TEST | gpg -e -a -r emanuele.paolini@gmail.com > test.gpg

$ gpg -d < test.gpg
gpg: encrypted with 1024-bit ELG key, ID CBABC188BB23CD11, created 2003-05-22
      "Emanuele Paolini <emanuele.paolini@unipi.it>"
gpg: public key decryption failed: Operation cancelled
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

$ gpg --list-secret-keys
/home/paolini/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
--------------------------------
sec   dsa1024 2003-05-22 [SC]
      848EA2CE420E06FF22E88DED7F0D73E98288DA05
uid           [ultimate] Emanuele Paolini <emanuele.paolini@unipi.it>
uid           [ultimate] Emanuele Paolini <e.paolini@sns.it>
uid           [ultimate] Emanuele Paolini <paolini@math.unifi.it>
uid           [ultimate] Emanuele Paolini <paolini@unifi.it>
uid           [ultimate] Emanuele Paolini <emanuele.paolini@gmail.com>
ssb   elg1024 2003-05-22 [E]
```

The same commands work fine on my personal computer.

- Maybe, there was a problem copying the keys?
- Maybe, there is a problem over the ssh connection?

**update**
The problem is related to the ssh connection. In fact if I try the command from the console of the server it works correctly (opens a window to ask for the password)... So it has something to do with pinentry. My ssh connection had X enabled and working.

**update 2**
I have tried changing the pinentry alternative as suggested by @Olivier. I can choose only between `pinentry-gnome3` (the default) and `pinentry-cursers`. I choose the latter and, unfortunately, I get the error "Inappropriate ioctl for device"...

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

`sudo update-alternatives --config pinentry`

Choose the `pinentry-curses` or `pinentry-tty` alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it is not working for me, see update 2 in my question.

Comment: You can try `pinentry-tty`, install with: `sudo apt install pinentry-tty`